# CSS Content attribute for IMG tag

Tags: css

```
img:after {
   content:attr(title);
}
```

This is not working, probably because the img tag is empty, no closing tag. Any workaround to fix this without js?

Comment: In what browser is it not working? What does the corresponding HTML look like?

Comment: Only works in Opera. The html is a simple img tag: <img src="asd.jpg" title="asd"/>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`img` is a **replaced element**, and the [w3c CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) says:

> Note. This specification does not
>   fully define the interaction of
>   :before and :after with replaced
>   elements (such as IMG in HTML). This
>   will be defined in more detail in a
>   future specification.

I don't know about any "future specification" that took place. It does not work in Chrome, that's for sure :).

Comment: no other answer, i guess its not possible, so thanks, köszi:)