# CSS - Style the title from the image tag

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm trying to style the title from the image tag.

I have search other question but can´t it put working in my project.

But I can´t make any changes.

Someone can give me hand with this pls?

**my code:**

```css
table.tablesorter tbody tr td a:hover img[title]:after
{
 content: attr(title);
 padding: 4px 8px;
 color: #FFF;
 background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<table class="tablesorter" style="width:98% !important">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
               .....
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

 <tbody>            
            <tr>
                <td>
                   ..........
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit","Account", new { id=item.UserId })">
                        <img src="~/Content/images/icon_edit.png" title="Edit"/>
                    </a>
               </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>

 <tfooter>
 </tfooter>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `content: attr(title);`, not `content: attr(data-title);` - you don't have a data attribute.

Also, it seems `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements are not defined for `img` - you may have to use something else:
[CSS Content attribute for IMG tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6009176/7586)

Working Example (when the image is missing): http://jsfiddle.net/DMAFm/
Another example, with the `title` on the `<a>` tag: http://jsfiddle.net/DMAFm/1/

Comment: @user2232273 - I checked further - it looks like `::after` just doesn't work for `<img>`: I added a link.

Comment: @Kobi.. its working now.. but is it possible to desactivate the default tootltip? what i mean is: its showing the tooltip i want but still shows the normal tooltip too

Comment: @user2232273 - Sure! just don't use the `title` attributes. You can use a data attribute, like `data-title`, which is pretty funny, in a way `:)`