# Wordpress image details - enable link title attribute

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Since the 'title' attribute is an global attribute, I would like to use it for setting **link title attribute** for the `<a>` tag from wordpress image details GUI. [image]

I want this so that I am able to fetch the  title as the picture title in my gallery like this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/4o39j2xj/

I don't think it is possible to use the `content: attr(title);`
from the `<img>` tag because it is a closing tag, and the :after part won't work the same way as the `<a>` tag (correct me if I am wrong).

Is there a function to enable **link title attribute** option in the wordpress image detailis?

Comment: Relevant question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009176/css-content-attribute-for-img-tag

Comment: This is what I am referring to regarding the '<img>' tag. This is no solution!

Comment: It just shows that probably there is ***no*** sollution